# No FFTW Option when Configuring ITK with CMake on Windows

Tags: cmake, fftw, imagej, itk

I've been trying to use the Tubular Geodesics tool for Simple Neurite Tracer in ImageJ *from Windows*, and I'm following the instructions on the site (found here: https://github.com/fethallah/tubularity).

I've successfully built FFTW, and I'm trying to configure ITK with CMake, but when I do so, the FFTW options that I'm supposed to see aren't appearing (even though I'm pretty sure I built FFTW correctly - I was able to successfully build the sample tutorial solution in VC 2015).

Below screenshot shows the output from configuring ITK in Cmake: 
[Screenshot of ITK configure output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSeMz.png)

I should also have USE_FFTWD, USE_FFTWF, and USE_REVIEW as options to check, but I can't find these.

Answer (score 0):

`ITK_USE_FFTWD` and `ITK_USE_FFTWF` are "Advanced" options. To use FFTW on Windows, you also need to turn on `ITK_USE_SYSTEM_FFTW`. Then you will need to set some paths (include directory and libraries). Here is a screenshot from one of my builds:
[image]